# Spring Boot MVC application with Postgresql deployment failed in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, heroku, spring-boot, heroku-postgres

I have a Spring Boot MVC project. It works fine with h2 database and also fine in local postgre database with following **application.properties** configuration

```
spring.datasource.url=myUrl
spring.datasource.username=myUsername
spring.datasource.password=myPassword
```

But when I am trying to deploy it in Heroku it is getting this following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

If I use this configuration

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=herokuPostgreSqlDbUrl
spring.datasource.username=herokuUsername
spring.datasource.password=mherokuPassword
```

I am getting this when try to run my project from STS and failed deployment.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@17a3dff6 
>   returned null for URL:myUrl

My pom is :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can any body help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proper JDBC url. See: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-postgresql/

Comment: I am using spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgres://ec2-54-235-124-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/xyzDbname as jdbc url is it ok ?